# Writable nested serializer method getting an Error while posting a request

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

**models.py**

```
class Client(models.Model):


    client_id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    org = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='org',null=True)
    product = models.ManyToManyField(Product,related_name='product')
    client_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    client_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    client_logo = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to,storage=DownloadableS3Boto3Storage, null=True, blank=True)
    currency = MoneyField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default_currency='INR', null=True)
    billing_method = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email_id = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    mobile_no = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    street_address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    industry = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    company_size = models.IntegerField()
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    is_active = models.IntegerField(default=0, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)


    class Meta:
        db_table = "client_master"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client_name
```

**serializers.py**

```
class Client_Serializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #product_name = Product_Serializers(many=True)
    product = Product_Serializers(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('client_id','currency','billing_method','first_name','last_name','description','street_address','city','state','country','pincode','industry','company_size','client_name', 'contact_no','mobile_no', 'email_id','client_logo','client_code','product',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        products_data = validated_data.pop('product')
        product = Product.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for product_data in products_data:
            Product.objects.create(product=product, **product_data)
        return product
```

Data receiving on GET method

```
{
            "client_id": 3,
            "currency": "0.05",
            "billing_method": "credit card",
            "first_name": "career",
            "last_name": "lab",
            "description": "NA",
            "street_address": "tiliconveli",
            "city": "tirunelveli",
            "state": "tamilnadu",
            "country": "India",
            "pincode": "600200",
            "industry": "software",
            "company_size": 100,
            "client_name": "techfetch",
            "contact_no": "1234567890",
            "mobile_no": "1234567890",
            "email_id": "icanio@gamil.com",
            "client_logo": "https://icanio-project-management.s3.amazonaws.com/client_logo/sup_bat_fDauRxK.jpg",
            "client_code": "TFH",
            "product": [
                {
                    "product_id": 5,
                    "product_name": "time"
                }
            ]
        }
```

But while posting it in the same format it is not getting posted, showing like

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "code": 400,
    "data": {
        "product": [
            "This field is required."
        ]
    },
    "message": "success"
}
```

**Views.py** for reference

```
class Client_Viewset(DestroyWithPayloadMixin,viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    renderer_classes = (CustomRenderer, )
    queryset=models.Client.objects.all()
    serializer_class=serializers.Client_Serializers
    parser_classes = [MultiPartParser, FormParser]



    filter_fields = (
        'client_id',
        'client_name',
        'client_code',
        'org_id',
    )
```

How can I post the same data which I get in the GET request of Product field. Please help me resolve this as I was stuck in there for two days. I tried so many ways and end up not getting posted.

**Product model**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "product_master"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product_name
```

**product serializer**

```
class Product_Serializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ('product_id','product_name',)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your code, the `Client_Serializers` is for `Client` model but the `create` method is not creating any `Client` object.

`Client_Serializers` should be something on these lines -

```
class Client_Serializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    product = Product_Serializers(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = ('client_id','currency','billing_method','first_name','last_name','description','street_address','city','state','country','pincode','industry','company_size','client_name', 'contact_no','mobile_no', 'email_id','client_logo','client_code','product',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        products_data = validated_data.pop('product')
        client = Client.objects.create(**validated_data) # Create a client object
        for product_data in products_data:
            Product.objects.create(client=client, **product_data)
        return client
```

Comment: when I create I still getting an error as product field is required. I entered the input for product field as {
                    "product_id": 5,
                    "product_name": "time"
                } 
But it is still throwing as "product": [
            "This field is required."
        ]. Can you please help me to do that.

Comment: Can you post your `Product` model?

Comment: I have updated in the question

Comment: Can you also post the `Product_Serializers`?

Comment: added in the question, please check and help me get through this, thanks in advance

Comment: Product model and serializer looks fine to me. Can you please show how you are sending the post request? Are you using Postman, curl, Django form or any other tool?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244259/discussion-between-krskara-and-vinoth-kumar).

Comment: can you please look into the chat discussion